Rails 7.1.3 - my javascript function is not found when invoking window.onload on page load
I have an application on Rails 7.1.3.4, upgraded from Rails 6.  I am in the process of converting to using import maps for Javascript that the application uses.  I am not using Turbo and Stimulus in this application.  On one of my pages I invoke window.onload to run a javascript function residing in one of my javascript files.  When I run the page, I get an error in the console saying that the function is not defined.  I checked and the javascript file is loaded in the page, so I think that I'm defining my import maps and imports properly.  I cannot figure out why the function cannot be accessed.  Any help appreciated!
Here's the error message that I get in the console when the page is loaded:
Uncaught ReferenceError: setConfPicksDsply is not defined
at window.onload (edit:2163:28)
Here's the relevant code in the view(it's at the end of the view file):
</div>
<%= javascript_tag "window.onload = function(){setConfPicksDsply();}" %>
<% end %>

The function setConfPicksDsply() resides in the file confnosprdpicks.js:
function setConfPicksDsply() {  
    // console.log("entering setConfPicksDsply()");
    set_page_info_dialog("info_button");
    setConfidencePoolSchedDsply();
    set_picks_dsply();
    set_sched_pnts_picked();
    var nTimeToNextGame = time_to_next_game();
    // console.log(nTimeToNextGame);
;   if (nTimeToNextGame > 0)
        {
            // console.log("about to call setTimeout");
            setTimeout(gm_expiration_confidence,time_adjusted_for_max_settimeout_val(nTimeToNextGame));
        }
}

The javascript file in the HTML is:


<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/confnosprdpicks-60401ca8e1ca41b15e45331a22235f5dae41ed4cf88beda020a167403337da36.js">



and I can see that the function is in the file when I open it.  Any ideas on how I can get the function to be recognized and run?  Thanks!
Update 11/1/2024:
Hi Max,  Thanks for your suggestions.  I have been trying to get your first suggestion (place the function into global scope), as that would seem to be the least disruptive, short term way to fix the problem.  But when I try this, I keep running into the same problem of the browser throwing an "Uncaught reference..setConfPicksDsply not defined" message.  The js statement that I tried is "window.setConfPicksDsply = setConfPicksDsply" and I have located it inline in the page as follows:
<%= javascript_tag "window.setConfPicksDsply = setConfPicksDsply;
window.onload = function(){setConfPicksDsply();}" %>

I also tried this in application.js:
import "jquery"
// import "jquery-ujs"
import "confnosprdpicks"
window.setConfPicksDsply = setConfPicksDsply;

But I get the same error in either case.
Do I have the syntax correct or should I be putting the global assignment statement in another location?

You would have to place the function in the global scope eg window.setConfPicksDsply = .... A better idea through then putting inline scripts in the view is to just replace the body tag in your layout with <body data-controller="<%= controller_name>" data-action="<%= action_name %>"> use those data attributes to "hook in" your javascript to the right pages. It avoids the scoping issues and keeps the concerns separated.

You just add a simple guard statement to the top of the event handler to ensure that it fires on the right page let data = document.body.dataset; if !(data["controller"] == "foo" && data["action"] == "bar") return;. It will make it a lot easier to move to stimulus if your JS isn't a mush that's spread out all over your view files.

You would have to assign you function to a global in the file where you're actually defining the function. Not in your inline script tag. But again don't shoot yourself in the foot by approaching javascript like its 1998 - using this approach with import-maps is like putting wooden wheels on a race car.
